# Equal space between numerator and denominator in fraction

Tags: spacing, fractions

I'm working on a school book that requires spacing between numerator and denominator to be of equal size. Is it possible to achieve this in LaTeX.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example which shows the problem?

Comment: I took the liberty to correct an error in the title of your question and to delete the final greetings, since it is not customary,  on this site, to include them in questions.  Why do you think that (La)TeX yields uneven spacing in fractions?  What’s wrong with `$\frac{a}{b}$`, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, they are already the same height, except for the unused space below and above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]% #1=numerator, #2=denominator
{\frac{\vphantom{#2}#1}{\vphantom{#1}#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{$\displaystyle \frac{A^2_0}{x}$} \fbox{$\displaystyle \myfrac{A^2_0}{x}$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]